# Current time (specific timezone) on a label

Tags: ios, xcode, label, nstimer, nstimezone

I am making an iOS app on the first page I want to show current time for specific country time zone

on label. What do I need to program to make only time (HH:MM) show on label. My specific country

timezone is Bangkok, Thailand (GMT+7). Thanks for your help! :)

```
This is screen shot link to the label. I haven't program anything yet
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnyq0m9s9dkk0eb/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-08%20at%202.41.50%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
// retrive the time regarding info.
NSDate *t = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// line below formats your time.
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
// now get the current time fomated 
NSString *ct = [df stringFromDate:t];
NSLog(@"%@",ct);

// set your label
self.lbl.text = ct;
```